# RestKit - Error Domain Code 1001

Tags: ios, json, restkit-0.20

OK, so I've reviewed almost every single one of the other questions on this site, to no avail.

Here's my JSON that comes back from a REST service:

```
{
 "errors" :     {};
 "result" :     {
    "messagebody" : "Hello!";
    "timestamp" : "2014-08-21T04:12:28.4689099+00:00";
 };
 "success" :    {};
}
```

I am trying to pull out the result object via RestKit v0.20.3

Here's a block of my code where it gets configured/executed:

```
- (void) configureRestKit
{

NSURL *cminstance = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://<domain>"];
AFHTTPClient *cmclient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:cminstance];

RKObjectManager *objmgr = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:cmclient];

RKObjectMapping *messageMap = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Message class]];
[messageMap addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"messagebody" : @"messagebody", @"timestamp": @"timestamp"}];
messageMap.forceCollectionMapping = YES;
RKResponseDescriptor *descriptor =
[RKResponseDescriptor
 responseDescriptorWithMapping:messageMap
 method:RKRequestMethodGET
 pathPattern:@"/v1/app/e51cb2dd24af47a49232b942210e758d/text?f=test"
 keyPath:@"result"
 statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objmgr addResponseDescriptor:descriptor];
}

- (IBAction)helloButtonClicked:(id)sender {

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"X-App-ApiKey" value:@"2c130c75dc9f4c2c8ef7c8753e8b7c56"];
NSLog(@"ResponseDescriptors %@", [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] responseDescriptors]);
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/v1/app/e51cb2dd24af47a49232b942210e758d/text?f=test" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

    _Response.text = [mappingResult.dictionary objectForKey:@"messagebody"];

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     _Response.text = @"Something went wrong.";
 }];
}
```

Here's the error from the trace:

> 2014-08-21 00:12:30.653 The-App[13924:3707] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:208 GET 'http:///v1/app/e51cb2dd24af47a49232b942210e758d/text?f=test' (200 OK / 0 objects) [request=2.7297s mapping=0.0000s total=2.7365s]:
>   error=Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No response descriptors match the response loaded." UserInfo=0xb164380 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http:///v1/app/e51cb2dd24af47a49232b942210e758d/text?f=test, NSLocalizedFailureReason=A 200 response was loaded from the URL 'http:///v1/app/e51cb2dd24af47a49232b942210e758d/text?f=test', which failed to match all (0) response descriptors:, NSLocalizedDescription=No response descriptors match the response loaded., keyPath=null, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http:///v1/app/e51cb2dd24af47a49232b942210e758d/text?f=test, NSUnderlyingError=0xb1641c0 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched."}
>   response.body={"success":{},"errors":{},"result":{"messagebody":"Hello!","timestamp":"2014-08-21T04:12:28.4689099+00:00"}}

Any ideas here on how to troubleshoot? I've been banging my head on this one for a few hours and google has not been my friend.

**EDIT:** The Response Descriptors

```
2014-08-22 10:41:21.580 Apprenda-CloudMine-App[10987:60b] ResponseDescriptors (
"<RKResponseDescriptor: 0x17826c180 method=(GET) pathPattern=/v1/app/e51cb2dd24af47a49232b942210e758d/text?f=test keyPath=result statusCodes=200-299 : <RKObjectMapping:0x17826bfc0 objectClass=Message propertyMappings=(\n    \"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1780499f0 timestamp => timestamp>\",\n    \"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x17804cf30 messagebody => messagebody>\"\n)>>"
```

)

Thanks!
-Chris

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON to me. Is that really what you are getting back from your service? I would imagine it should look like `{
 "errors":{}
 "result":{
    "messagebody":"Hello!",
    "timestamp":"2014-08-21T04:12:28.4689099+00:00"
 },
 success:{}
}`

In fact, your error message suggests that is exactly what you are getting back.

Comment: Also, can you show us what the line `NSLog(@"ResponseDescriptors %@", [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] responseDescriptors]);` prints?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm getting back from the service. I'll edit my question with the response descriptors.

Comment: and yes, you are correct. the above json is prettified. I'll edit to show valid json (good catch).

Comment: Try this solution, it worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77053689/8440021

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error indicates that the path between your request and your response descriptor are not matching. It is subtle, the `(0) response descriptors` in the error message also indicate to me that there are no response descriptors for that path. For more information on the error messages for RestKit path mismatches see [this](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1060) GitHub issue.

Why then are you getting a path mismatch? After all, the path in your request is *exactly* the same as your path in your response descriptor. It would seem that your problem is likely the GET parameter specified in the response descriptors path. You need to remove the get parameter from your response descriptors path since it is not technically part of the path.

It should be the following instead.

```
[RKResponseDescriptor
 responseDescriptorWithMapping:messageMap
 method:RKRequestMethodGET
 pathPattern:@"/v1/app/e51cb2dd24af47a49232b942210e758d/text"
 keyPath:@"result"
 statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Thanks to [Flaviu Simihaian](http://flaviusim.com/blog/2013/04/28/restkit-0-dot-20-no-response-descriptors-match-the-response-loaded/) for realizing this.